# Not able to create a trigger with if condition in MySql 5.5.27

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two table A and B.

Table A have 4 column: id, name, age, status 
* status may be only active and inactive
Table B have: id, age, changedOn, idOfA

I want to write an update trigger in Table A which will only
work when Table A's updated row status will be 'inactive'.

I have tried to write a trigger like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `before_A_update` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `A` FOR EACH ROW
IF New.status = 'inactive' THEN
UPDATE B
SET age= (NEW.age + 10),
changedOn = NOW()
WHERE idOfA= NEW.id
END IF;
END;
```

But it is showing me an error and trigger is not created.

Comment: Unclear. What are you asking for ? I see no question.

Comment: Please add any errors and make the issue clear with what you have. Maybe include the expected results and examples if you can. This will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

2 things , you need a delimiter at the beginning and also missing the `begin` clause, it should be as

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `before_A_update` before UPDATE ON `A` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF New.status = 'inactive' THEN 
  UPDATE B
  SET age= (NEW.age + 10),
  changedOn = NOW()
  WHERE idOfA= NEW.id
 END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: But still it is not working. And I am using MySql Trigger window for creating the trigger.

Comment: If you are using the 3rd party app like phpmyadmin, then you need to select the delimiter there and remove the delimiter block from the above code. So no need of `delimiter //` and the last line would be `end;` , no need of `delimiter ;`

Comment: Hey, 
I have also tried in this way. But it is also not working. I am a little bit confused that why this normal thing is not working.